# trouble using angularjs with slim in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, slim-lang

I've finally decided to give angularjs a whirl and i'm running into some early trouble.

I'm using Rails 3.2 and the Slim template gem for the view.

I'm just trying the example from the angularjs site here: http://angularjs.org/#todo-html

Here's the relevant bit:

```
 <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining</span>
```

Which in slim would be something like:

```
div(ng-controller="TodoCtrl")
  span {{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining
```

The problem is Slim just prints:

```
{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining
```

literally as a string.

Anyone able to get Slim and Angular to play together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

I had to go into my layout and do this:

```
html(ng-app='')
```

You can probably add that to a div on the particular page also.

```
div(ng-app='')
  div(ng-controller="TodoCtrl")
    span {{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining
```

Hopefully this helps someone.  It took me a bit to figure out.

Comment: Any particular reason to bother with the parentheses ? You could simply use ``html ng-app=''``.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it like so:

```
html [ng-app]
```

Or:

```
div [ng-app]
  div [ng-controller="TodoCtrl"]
    span {{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining
```